# How do I bring the Dropdown Navigation menu over the flash banner?

Tags: flash, drop-down-menu

As you can see in this website I've created http://mssre.host.org/ [link now obsolete], the drop-down menu is behind the flash banner. I've tried the 'wmode' to opaque and transparent, and also tried using javascript, but no matter what I do, the flash stay in front of drop-down menu.
Is there a way to get rid of this problem?
Thanks in advance!

E: I also tried what http://www.toolgal.com/ had done. But again, failed. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `wmode` to `transparent` and use `absolute positioning` for your `divs`.

> In your code for the flash file, add the following:

```
<param name=”wmode” value=”transparent”>
```

> In the “embed” area, you need to add this: `wmode=”transparent”`
>
> Add your div with absolute positioning and off you go.

http://www.brianyerkes.com/swfobject-help-when-placing-a-div-over-flash/